# How can I view the source code of the actual package version online?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, package-management, launchpad, source-code

I was trying to find online source code repository for [BleachBit package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bleachbit) for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

So I started by visiting search on https://packages.ubuntu.com and found [the source package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/bleachbit).

Clicking on both *Debian Source Repository* (*Subversion*) on the right part of page →

> [image: right side]

or on the links in the bottom ↓

> [image: bottom part of the page]

went me to non-existent (404) pages as `anonscm.debian.org` is down.

Then I tried to visit [Bleachbit page on the Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bleachbit) to get its [source code](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bleachbit). And what is interesting I can get only the code for the not-so-new [Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) branch](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bleachbit/+branches).

How can I view the source code of the actual package version online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

If you see links with *anonscm.debian.org* or *git.debian.org* then visit [Debian Salsa GitLab repositories](https://salsa.debian.org/public) and the search for the package here.

---

## Bugs

Three bugs related to this problem exist:

1. Bug of the https://packages.ubuntu.com , it should not show dead links with *anonscm.debian.org* and *git.debian.org* - I reported it to launchpad as [bug 1812562](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pkg-website/+bug/1812562);
2. Bug of `apt-get` - it should not show broken links with *anonscm.debian.org* - I reported it to launchpad as [bug 1812564](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1812564);
3. Bug of `apt-get` - it should not show broken links with * http://git.debian.org* - I reported it to launchpad as [bug 1812577](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1812577).

## Solution

The *svn://anonscm.debian.org* is down after Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (and 14.04 LTS) release, so one should use its successor - [Debian Salsa GitLab repositories](https://salsa.debian.org/public) then search for needed package here (or visit source package page for newer [*bionic* release on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/bleachbit)).

As the result one can get the correct URLs for the source package:

> Debian Package Source Repository (VCS: Git)
>     * https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/applications/bleachbit.git
>   Debian Package Source Repository (Browsable)
>     * https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/applications/bleachbit

Here one can switch to the needed version branch (1.10-1 in this case):

> https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/applications/bleachbit/tree/debian/1.10-1

and view any needed source code file.